# Pandas_profiling package is causing errror

Tags: import, package, pandas-profiling

When I try to from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport I'm getting this error:

> PydanticImportError: 'BaseSettings' has been moved to the 'pydantic-settings' package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details

Error message that I am seeing

[image]

Before this, I did `!pip install pandas-profiling`, it works - getting error after this

I am trying this code:

```
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, include the _full_ error message in your question. In this specific cast, it's important to see _where_ `BaseSettings` was imported from. You can [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding pandas-profiling was deprecated quite a while now.

Try the following please:

#this will ensure that the most recent version is installed
!pip install ydata-profiling

from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport